# Onde colocar os métodos de requisição assíncrona seguindo os padrões ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Eu sempre coloquei no Controller da View, é a maneira mais correta de se fazer? me veio a duvida pois percebi que estou enchendo minha view de métodos assíncronos, e gostaria de deixar isso tudo separado para eu não me perder.

Nunca li nada sobre boas praticas de onde colocar esses métodos, gostaria de saber qual o padrão de desenvolvimento relacionado a métodos para requisição assíncrona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, é no Controller da view que os métodos se requisição devem ficar, sejam síncronos ou assíncronos.

Seguindo a premissa de SoC (Separation of Concerns), sua `Controller` deve conter apenas os métodos de requisição (`Action/ActionResult`), o assíncronismo é só um detalhe do funcionamento neste caso.

O importante é que métodos que realmente exponham *como* o serviço é feito, como chamadas ao banco de dados e manipulação de dados, que configuraria uma camada de acesso ao banco ou serviços sejam colocados em outro projeto e apenas *chamados* pelo seu projeto Web para que ele não fique muito carregado e confuso.

Adicionar o sufixo `Async` aos nomes dos métodos assíncronos também é uma boa prática.

Um exemplo claro de como seria um método de requisição assíncrono seria esse:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetReportsAsync(ReportsViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Toda lógica é feita aqui.
        ReportingResult result = await reportingService.GenerateReport(model);
        if (result.Success)
        {
            return Redirect("~/home");
        }
        else
        {
            // View de erro
        }
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Limpo e claro (e assíncrono). Expõem apenas o necessário e não deixa o código sujo.

Detalhe importante sobre `assíncronismo`:

Nunca utilize o método `Task.Run` na `controller`, o assíncronismo deve começar de dentro para fora, ou seja, nas camadas mais interiores você identifica operações que necessitam ser assíncronas, como chamadas ao banco de dados, aí então pode expor o método como `Task` ou `async Task` e na sua Controller chamar o método com `await`, igual ao meu exemplo. Esse é uma ótima prática de implementação assíncrona ensinada por Stephen Cleary.

Segue um post da Microsoft(em inglês) que fala sobre requisição assíncrona, performance e alguns dos recursos oferecidos pelo ASP.NET MVC: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4

Comment: Sua resposta foi muito satisfatória, não sabia do sufixo, do await ou do task por exemplo. Mas sua resposta já me deu um norte. Valeu !

Comment: Vou acrescentar um link da microsoft sobre requisição assíncrona.