# Porque quando estou tratando um erro não carrega o arquivo _Layout?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

Estou fazendo um tratamento de erro usando o Json Result, quando exibi a mensagem de erro deveria exibir a página formada assim como rege no arquivo _Layout, portanto a página está carregando toda em branco, alguém sabe como resolver? Abaixo a imagem de como esta sendo exibido!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui o meu homeController:

```
using ReportandoErro.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ReportandoErro.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Teste()
        {

            var response = new ResponseViewModel();
            try
            {
                throw new Exception("Oops, ocorreu um erro");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return ErroCapturado(e);
            }
            return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public ActionResult ErroCapturado(Exception ex)
        {
            var response = new ResponseViewModel
            {
                Data = ex.Data,
                Sucesso = false,
                Mensagem = ex.Message
            };

            return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
    }

}
```

Aqui meu AccountViewModels:

```
public class ResponseViewModel
    {
        public object Data { get; set; }
        public bool Sucesso { get; set; }
        public string Mensagem { get; set; }
    }
```

E aqui a view chamada teste:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Teste";
}
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@model ReportandoErro.Models.ResponseViewModel

<h2>Teste</h2>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //debugger;
        gerandoRelatorio();
        function gerandoRelatorio() {
            $.getJSON("Home/Teste", function (response) {

                if (response.sucesso) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                }
                else {
                    alert(data.mensagem);
                }

            }).fail(function (response) {
                //Erro genérico
                alert("Não foi possível processar a sua requisição");

            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para renderizar a página ,você precisa retornar uma `View()` nesse caso você só retorna `Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)`. Crie sempre `Actions` separadas para suas requisições Ajax. Para solucionar, basta criar uma `Action` separada **apenas** para a sua requisição, segue o código:

```
using ReportandoErro.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ReportandoErro.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Teste()
        {

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Ajax_Teste()
        {
            var response = new ResponseViewModel();
            try
            {
                throw new Exception("Oops, ocorreu um erro");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return ErroCapturado(e);
            }
            return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        public ActionResult ErroCapturado(Exception ex)
        {
            var response = new ResponseViewModel
            {
                Data = ex.Data,
                Sucesso = false,
                Mensagem = ex.Message
            };

            return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
    }

}
```

Criei a `Action` `Ajax_Teste` que executa a requisição Ajax e retorna **Json**.

E dentro do Javascript onde você executa a requisição, você vai chamar  `Ajax_Teste` e não  `Teste`:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Teste";
}
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@model ReportandoErro.Models.ResponseViewModel

<h2>Teste</h2>

<script type = "text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function () {
//debugger;
gerandoRelatorio();
    function gerandoRelatorio()
    {
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "Home/Ajax_Teste"
        })
        .done(function (response) {
            if (response.Sucesso)
            {
               console.log(response.Mensagem);
            }
            else
            {
                alert(response.Mensagem);
            }
        })
        .fail(function(response) {
            //Erro genérico
            alert("Não foi possível processar a sua requisição");
        });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Sendo assim, a `Action` `Teste` retorna a sua `View()` e a Action `Ajax_Teste` retorna seu `Json()`.

Fica a dica de um conteúdo sobre Requisição assíncrona/síncrona nos padrões MVC [nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/241420/onde-colocar-os-m%C3%A9todos-de-requisi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ass%C3%ADncrona-seguindo-os-padr%C3%B5es-asp-net-mvc).

Para exibir a resposta você pode utilizar o que já estava no seu código JS: `console.log(response.Mensagem)` lembrando que o Javascript é Case-sensitive, você estava chamando `if(response.sucesso)` o correto é `if(response.Sucesso)`.

Se você quiser inserir na sua View, você pode manipular o DOM. Embaixo do `<H2>`, adicione a seguinte linha:

```
<p id="mensagem"></p>
```

E no seu Javascript adicione:

```
$("#mensagem").text(response.Mensagem);
```

Assim ele preencherá o paragrafo com a mensagem.

Comment: Então Leonardo, eu fiz aqui, portanto esta retornando a view teste, porém não esta exibindo o log de erro, como fazer para que esse log de erro seja exibido nessa view?

Comment: E eu percebi outra coisa, ele não ta entrando nesso Ajax_Teste

Comment: @WPfan da uma olhada

Comment: @WPfan que framework você está utilizando para realizar a requisição?

Comment: estou usando asp.net mvc

Comment: @WPfan atualiza seu Javascript, vÊ se desse modo vai

Comment: Ainda continua do mesmo jeito, ja to quase dando um soco no notebook kkkkkk

Comment: Você precisa debugar, saber se está chegando na action Ajax_Teste, depois, caso esteja chegando, saber se está retornando algo. faça esse teste e me diga até que ponto está funcionando certinho

Comment: ele não ta entrando no Ajax_Teste, esse é o problema!!

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72465/discussion-between-wpfan-and-leonardo-bonetti).